# Count distinct values in multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a database table

```
 projectNo| process | procLeader | procCheker  |  
 ---------+---------+------------+-------------+
 16090001 | ANM     | ari        | barry       |
 16090001 | BLD     | ben        | ben         |
```

I want to count distinct variables inside multiple columns procLeader and procChecker, so i want to display column name `total 3` as ben appears 2

What i did so far is tried to `union` both columns into one but cant get how to count it now.
My query:

```
select distinct `procLeader`
as tot from process as tot where projectNo=16090016
union
select distinct `procChecker`
from process from process as tot where projectNo=16090016
```

Or maybe there is another way to count distinct variables? Thanks
I want to final result be like this

```
 total| 
 -----+
 3    |
```

Comment: Show us the expected result, as formatted table. (Same way as the sample data.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UNION` between the two columns to remove duplicate and `COUNT(*)` to get count result.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Total
FROM
( SELECT `procLeader` FROM process where projectNo=16090016
  UNION
  SELECT `procCheker` FROM process where projectNo=16090016
) AS tmp
```

No need to use **DISTINCT** as **UNION** operator removes duplicates from resultset

Comment: with your answer im getting same errors as from coments above, but query not running, just displaying errors: `An expression was expected. (near "(" at position 32)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 32)
This type of clause was previously parsed. (near "SELECT" at position 34)`

Answer (score 2):

You have to wrap your query in a subquery:

```
select count(distinct tot) as total
from (
  select distinct `procLeader` as tot 
  from process  
  where projectNo=16090016
union
  select distinct `procChecker`
  from process 
  where projectNo=16090016) as t
```

Comment: It works but also its working errors like: `An expression was expected(near (); Unexpected token(near (); This type of clause was previously parsed(near SELECT)` its showing exactly what i want but im getting this warnings?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) Total FROM (
SELECT procLeader AS tot FROM process WHERE projectNo=16090016
UNION
SELECT procChecker FROM process WHERE projectNo=16090016) t;
```

Comment: ok same for this, its working but im getting kind of warnings see comment on Giorgos Betsos answer

Comment: I think it requires semicolon at the end, can you please try updated one above.

Comment: still the same. The thing its working exactly as i want. it shows errors in query field but when im running query its fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use count(distinct)

```
select projectNumber, count(distinct procleader) as C1, count(distinct procChecker) as C2
from Table1
where projectNumber = 16090016 
group by projectNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Please let us know if you have any concerns or que.

```
select (count(distinct procChecker)+count(distinct procLeader)) as `Total` 
from process  
where projectNo=16090001
```